# Is it possible to install two versions of redis?

Tags: installation, redis

I want to use redis sentinel for some debugging but this forced me to download the latest unstable version of redis.  I was already running redis 2.6.13 and it was working fine.  I attempted to install this redis-unstable version on the same machine as redis 2.6.13 using http://redis.io/topics/quickstart and the install_server.sh but using port 6380 and different file names than the ones used to install redis 2.6.13.  For some reason although I am constantly referring to port 6380, at start up and in the redis-cli the port is still 6379.

Is this installation even possible? Why does the port stay the same?

I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: I just compiled redis from source and run it manually from the `src` directory when I need it. without installing anything.

Comment: @akonsu how exactly does one compile redis from source?

Comment: the official downloads page has the instructions: http://redis.io/download. basically, you download the `tar` archive, unpack it, and run `make` on it.

Answer (score 2):

To install another version just use the above one liner and follow the steps:

```
VERSION="2.6.14"
cd /tmp && wget -c "http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-${VERSION}.tar.gz"&& tar xvzf "redis-${VERSION}.tar.gz" && cd "redis-${VERSION}" && make && sudo make install && sudo ./utils/install_server.sh
```

Note: You will want to specify a different folder for "redis-server" in order to prevent conflicts

Comment: Hi FGRibreau, I currently have "redis-server" in /usr/local/bin. Does "redis-server" have to remain inside /usr/local/bin or can I place it elsewhere?

Comment: You can definitely place it somewhere else just don't forget to start it with the configuration file you want, for instance: $/path/to/redis-server /etc/redis/1234.conf

Comment: this response is outdated

Comment: @jmny fixed, only the download link was outdated, everything else still work as expected 